# Share authentication between rails 4 (devise) and ember.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, devise

In our company we decide to move our monolithic application currently developed in rails 4.2 to ember.js. And keep all back-end in rails. The first step I see, is authentication.

How to share devise authentication with my new fresh ember.js 2.17 app, without re-authenticate?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What difficulty are you having? One google search and I found https://github.com/the-refinery/ember-devise-simple-auth -- does that answer your question?? I'm voting to close, as StackOverflow is not really an appropriate place to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm currently working on a (very big) set of rails applications, with EmberJS front-ends. The authentication mechanism van vary quite a lot, depending on what you're actually trying to achieve. For example, are you integrating OAuth - e.g. facebook login? Does your authentication need to work *across multiple* sites? Are you using JWTs? Any other protocols, such as LDAP or SAML or AD? Are you integrating with legacy platforms? (How?) ..... I could write a whole *book* on the topic; you need to at least be more specific about your application design.